# getting error while using s3cmd with following config

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am trying s3cmd from command line and when i am configuring using `s3cmd --configure` following lines of information its asking me. I know I am giving proper `Access Key` and `Secret key`. But I think the problem is with `Default Region: Mumbai` or `S3 Endpoint: ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` or 
`DNS-style bucket+hostname:port template for accessing a bucket:`. My S3 bucket is in Mumbai, India.

```
Access Key: ASOMETHINGJFDGERCEMUA
Secret Key: 5q2tbwdf43/sdfsdfsdf/AopqPd73QaiN4fr3e3fv8wE
Default Region: Mumbai
S3 Endpoint: ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
DNS-style bucket+hostname:port template for accessing a bucket: %(bucket)s.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
Encryption password:
Path to GPG program: None
Use HTTPS protocol: True
HTTP Proxy server name:
HTTP Proxy server port: 0
```

Error:

ERROR: Test failed: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: I would have to agree with @JohnRotenstein. The AWS CLI is supported by AWS. I would highly recommend that over s3cmd.

Comment: There is a time and place where `s3cmd` rules over `aws s3 ...` s3cmd will allow you to stream data to your bucket while performing database dumps and more. Simply, time and place.

Answer (score 0):

For `Asia Pacific (Mumbai)`, use the following values.

```
Region: ap-south-1
S3 Endpoint: s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

Refer [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) for the complete list of S3 Endpoints.

**Note:** Check whether your version of `s3cmd` supports Signature Version 4.

Prefer Aws CLI over S3cmd.